# Submit selected checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jsp, checkbox, html-table

I need to add a function to my table so when multiple rows are selected by check boxes and then the "select" button is pressed another JSP page should popup to submit the selected rows. I want "select" button to just select the rows and popup the submit page for submission.

[image]
[image]

Table JSP:

```
<table id="summaryTable" class="tablesorter" > 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>&nbsp;</th>  
<th>Bar Code</th> 
<th>Origin</th> 
<th>Sender Name</th> 
<th>Recipient Name</th> 
<th>Receipt Date</th>
<th>Load Date</th>
<th>Forecast ISC</th>
<th>Actual ISC</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Source</th>
<th><input type="submit" name="selectCheckBox" value="Select"></th>
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<c:forEach items="${summary}" var="summary">

 <tr>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.eventDesc}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.origin}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.senderName}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.receiverName}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.receiptDate}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.loadDate}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.forecastIsc}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.actualIsc}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.country}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.source}" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the code to check the boxes selected but I do not understand what exactly do you want to do after that.

```
            $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"),function(){
                //your code here
            });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. If you notice I have a select button in check box column heading. I need that select button to select all the checked boxes in the table and then submit it to another jsp page for final submission.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clear the 'popup the submit page' part? 
For the first part the code should be something like this

```
$('[name="selectCheckBox"]').on('click', function() {
  $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  //$.ajax call here if you just want to post it to the backend
});
```

Comment: ok.. I added the image of my submission page (verificatiion Decision).  Submission page should popup when user checks a box and presses select button. On the Verification Decision page user selects one radio button for all the selected rows(which were selected by pressing select button on the table) and submits the form. I hope its not too confusing.

Comment: So basically select button should only select the check boxes and also pop up the verification Decision page to finally submit the selected rows from the Verification decision page..